# Kubernetes automatically remove resources no longer required

Tags: kubernetes

Using AWS CloudFormation, I can create a stack based on a template that includes all required resources. I can then create a new template, adding some resources, removing some, and changing description of others. I can then update the CloudFormation stack with the new template. CloudFormation will automatically remove any resources that are no longer in the template, add the new ones, and update modified resources. In addition, the update will roll back if any of the operations fails.

Is there an equivalent to this in Kubernetes, where I can just provide an updated configuration file, and have Kubernetes automatically compare that to the previous version and remove any resources that should no longer be there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For single resources (e.g. a single Pod or Deployment) Kubernetes will automatically reconcile the state. So it works in a similar manner as CloudFormation in that sense. If you change a deployment and remove a pod from it, Kubernetes will automatically remove the resources.

If you want to treat multiple resources as a single object, you can look at something like [Helm](https://helm.sh/), which simplifies packaging multiple Kubernetes resources together.

Answer (score 0):

Using deployment template will suffice your need, a deployment can be rollback at any time needed.

Rollout command when used with correct flags like "status/history/undo" should help you control the stack resource rollout or rollback..

```
kubectl rollout status deployment nginx
```

Check rollout History

```
kubectl rollout history deployment nginx
```

Rolling Back to a Previous Revision

```
kubectl rollout undo deployment nginx
```

In below example i created a deployment with two pods using deployment_v1.yaml file which has 2 containers inside a pod (nginx/redis)

`kubectl create -f deployment_v1.yaml --record=true`

deployment_v1.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: multi-container-deploy
  name: multi-container-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: multi-container
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: multi-container
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx-1
      - image: redis
        name: redis-2
```

Checking Status during rollout

```
$ kubectl rollout status deployment multi-container-deploy
Waiting for deployment "multi-container-deploy" rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
deployment "multi-container-deploy" successfully rolled out
```

Rollout history

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment multi-container-deploy
deployment.apps/multi-container-deploy
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         kubectl create --filename=deployment_v1.yaml --record=true
```

```
$ kubectl get all
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/multi-container-deploy-5fc8944c58-r4dt4   2/2     Running   0          60s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   32d

NAME                                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/multi-container-deploy   1/1     1            1           60s

NAME                                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/multi-container-deploy-5fc8944c58   1         1         1       60s
```

Now say we remove the redis pod from the original deployment by say kubectl edit command

```
kubectl edit deployments multi-container-deploy
```

Check new rollout status after edit as below

```
$ kubectl rollout status deployment multi-container-deploy
Waiting for deployment "multi-container-deploy" rollout to finish: 1 old replicas are pending termination...
Waiting for deployment "multi-container-deploy" rollout to finish: 1 old replicas are pending termination...
deployment "multi-container-deploy" successfully rolled out
```

Check new rollout history and we will see list updated as below (disadvantage of direct edit we will not have much info on what was done on step2)

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment multi-container-deploy
deployment.apps/multi-container-deploy
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         kubectl apply --filename=deployment_v1.yaml --record=true
2         kubectl apply --filename=deployment_v1.yaml --record=true
```

We can also check that the resource was successful removed and we only have pod running with one container.

```
$ kubectl get all
NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/multi-container-deploy-7cdb9cbf4-jr9nc   1/1     Running   0          4m36s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   32d

NAME                                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/multi-container-deploy   1/1     1            1           13m

NAME                                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/multi-container-deploy-5fc8944c58   0         0         0       13m
replicaset.apps/multi-container-deploy-7cdb9cbf4    1         1         1       4m36s
```

We can Undo above edit on deployment just by running below command

```
$ kubectl rollout undo deployment multi-container-deploy
deployment.apps/multi-container-deploy rolled back
```

If we check back we have the pod running back with two containers again.

```
$ kubectl get all
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/multi-container-deploy-5fc8944c58-xn4mz   2/2     Running   0          40s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   32d

NAME                                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/multi-container-deploy   1/1     1            1           15m

NAME                                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/multi-container-deploy-5fc8944c58   1         1         1       15m
replicaset.apps/multi-container-deploy-7cdb9cbf4    0         0         0       6m59s
```

And rollout history will be updated as below

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment multi-container-deploy
deployment.apps/multi-container-deploy
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
2         kubectl apply --filename=deployment_v2.yaml --record=true
3         kubectl apply --filename=deployment_v2.yaml --record=true
```

Comment: Based on what I have seen when creating a deployment, only resources described in that deployment configuration are managed, I want resources that were previously in my config file but are no longer there to be removed. e.g. "kubectl apply -f my-app.yaml" where my-app.yaml describes 3 resources (services, ingress, volumes, etc.). Then "kubectl apply -f my-app.yaml" where my-app.yaml now only describes 2 resources, and have the 3rd resource automatically removed.

Comment: I believe then as already answered in one of the other answers  on this post you will need Helm charts created for managing all the objects. Using deployment we will only be able to control pod(container) and replication set object.